# How to Enable Column Always Encrypted in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I read out some articles about Encryption on client side. I want to use Encryption Columns in SQL Server but that is not visible for me. Please look in to image:
[image]

How can i see  like this. Please help me
:[image]

Comment: The second screenshot is right clicking on a *database,* not a table or column.

Comment: Yeah I know but i also clicked on database but unable to find this option

Comment: There are tons of articles on how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by configuring Always Encripted using SSMS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-using-sql-server-management-studio